# Synchronize several instances of Windows Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, checkbox

I have a `Windows Forms Application` project with one `Windows Form`, and it's called `FormCheck`. `FormCheck` has just one `CheckBox`.

This executable is copied in three devices, so now Joe, Mary and Larry each have a device with an EXE of this `Windows Form`.

How can I synchronize all 3 tablets so that when Joe clicks on the `CheckBox` all three devices reflect the checked `CheckBox`? And again, if Mary unchecks the `CheckBox`, all three tablets show an unchecked `CheckBox` in their device? I know I can use a Timer, but I don't want to use it so that's why I'm asking here.

For a similar question, someone suggested using signalR, but that's overkill for such an easy application.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the applications to communicate with *each other* (difficult) or with a *central server* (easier)?  Just have a single location, reachable over the network by each of them, where you can store and retrieve data.  A database works well for this sort of thing.

Comment: @David, All three can access a database, Let's say that Joe clicks on the checkbox, how will the other instances of the Form know that the change has been made?

Comment: @rbhatup Can all three access a shared folder on the network ?

Comment: An easy option (i think) would be using `Sockets`, but one of the apps would need to be the server and the others clients...In this link you've got all you need [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6xa24z5(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @rbhatup: Either by polling the database or by having a central server sending out notifications (such as with SignalR).

Comment: @user3185569, there can be a shared network location, but like I wrote to David, how will the other two Forms know that a change has been made?

Comment: @David, a Timer or SignalR. With a Timer, there will be lag and it's a hit and I'm assuming that the user will _feel_ the lag from the constant DB check. And with SignalR it seems like overkill for something so simple.

Comment: @rbhatup check answer below on how to listen to network location changed

Comment: @user3185569 i feel i must say I'm really against using files for this type of communication between processes. In my experience it usually leads to  a lot of errors, like blocked files etc...

Comment: @Pikoh, let's say that I use a `Timer` to check the database every second. Will the Windows Form lag? For the purposes of the example, the table will have just has one row, so there won't be lag from the actual sql script.

Comment: Well..i did not advise you to use a timer but sockets. But anyway, i don't think it would lag, as long as the database is quick enough. You must also think if is necessary to check it each second...In fact, i think i would try anything else instead of a real time update of that checkbox,e.g., blocking the access so that only one application could modifiy the checkbox at a time. But it depends of your case

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at .Net Remoting in the System.Runtime.Remoting namespace maybe?

Comment: .Net Remoting is a legacy technology (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72x4h507%28VS.85%29.aspx).  WCF is the current technology.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options:

### Option 1: [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)

A `FileSystemWatcher` can listen to a specific network location and detect changes. You can come up with a file that you can store a value in and update it. All Applications will be notified of that change. Example in MSDN link above.

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
watcher.Path = "yourNetworkPath";
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
watcher.Filter = "*.txt";
watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    // read file and update checkbox
}
```

### Option 2: [IPC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.channels.ipc.ipcchannel.aspx)

Using Client/Server and socket messages.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't thought of using `FileSystemWatcher`. Is this something like a `Timer` or is it something that's more or less _real time_?

Comment: @rbhatup You get notified real time, i previously used the watcher over a network location and i got no issues. You might need to delay the reading for up to 1 second if you face any delay (For me in case of large files) but that is still faster than a database and more efficient for me.